# How to access different skills logo in png format to put in GitHub markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

These links provide images:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/git/git.png/
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/python/python.png/

But these links do not provide images:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/tableau/tableau.png/
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/github/github.png/
Above URL shows `400: Invalid request`

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All four of those give HTTP 400 for me. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Removing the trailing `/` from all four links makes them work, but the latter two give _404 not found_, not 400 invalid request. I'm not sure where they come from or why you think they should work, but double-check the URLs.